# How do I use a struct from a header file that has some other functions as well?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a struct (struct People) in a header file (usefulFunctions.h), and this header file has some other functions that aren't related to the struct.
In another header file (shoppers.h), I'm trying to create `std::vector<People *> shoppersToday`, but I get the following errors

> template argument 1 is invalid
>        `std::vector<People*> shoppersToday;`
>
> People wasn't declared in this scope

I have `#include "usefulFunctions.h"` in my shoppers.h file, but I have no idea why it doesn't work.

--- Edit 1 ---

```
//usefulFunctions.h
#ifndef USEFULFUNCTIONS_H
#define USEFULFUNCTIONS_H
#include "shoppers.h"

void isNoItemsInBag();

struct People{
Shoppers * shoppee;
};
#endif

//shoppers.h
#ifndef SHOPPERS_H
#define SHOPPERS_H
#include "usefulFunctions.h"
struct People;
class Shoppers{
 std::vector<People *> shoppersToday;
};
#endif
```

--- Edit 2 ---
Added `#include<shoppers.h>` in the usefulFunctions.h file, still getting the same error

--- Edit 3 ---
Adding `struct People` after the `#include`s seems to solve it. 
Thank you all for your feedback.

Comment: Is `People` in a namespace?

Comment: No, I've only declared it as struct People{...};

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It should contain just enough code to reproduce the error and no more.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added it in now.

Comment: `Shoppers` is undeclared in "usefulFunctions.h".  Are you actually including "usefulFunctions.h" in "shoppers.h"?  If so, then you have a circular include, and will need to break it with a forward declaration.

Comment: Thank you, I've added it in, but the error I get when I try to compile still says People wasn't declared in the scope

Comment: could you please try `std::vector<struct People*> shoppersToday;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, a declaration is only visible *below* the point where it's declared. So, for example, this is valid:

```
struct People { ... };
std::vector<People *> peoplePointers;
```

while this is not:

```
std::vector<People *> peoplePointers;   // INVALID
struct People { ... };
```

Your problem is that you're includeing `shoppers.h` *before* you declare `People`, so `shoppers.h` can't make use that declaration.

In your case, merely reordering things or switching around includes won't help, because you actually have a mutual dependency: `Shoppers` depends on `People` and vice versa.

Instead, you should write a *forward declaration*:

```
struct People;
```

This declares `People` as a class that exists, thereby allowing any code after that to refer to it . . . *provided that* that code doesn't need to know the contents of the class. So, something like this is fine:

```
struct People;
std::vector<People *> peoplePointers;
struct People { ... };
```

but this is not:

```
struct People;
std::vector<People> peoplePointers; // INVALID
struct People { ... };
```

because `std::vector<People>` needs to know the size of a `People` instance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if I had to do something like `std::vector<People> peoplePointers`, how should I go about that?

Comment: @user7999116: I think that most circular dependencies are resolvable one way or another. For example, it seems to be OK (for reasons I don't fully understand) to have a `std::vector<People>` as a data member of another class, as long as `People` is fully declared before any code that needs to instantiate that other class. The only case where I think you really can't resolve it is if you want an instance of class to ultimately contain another instance of the same class. Something like `class A { B b; }; class B { A a; }` can never be resolved, because then each `A` would contain another `A`.